# Regular expression to match all between <> which falls between square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following string for example :

```
[noreplace1]<noreplace2>noreplace3[<replace1><replace2>noreplace4<replace3>noreplace5]<noreplace6>noreplace7"
```

I need to replace everything between <> which is contained within square brackets - **not matching the square brackets themselves.**

I'm using preg_replace and have tried the following :

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\[\<)(\<(.*?)*\>)*(?=\])/', '', $str);
```

But this doesn't give the desired results.

The expected output should be : [noreplace1]noreplace3[noreplace4noreplace5]noreplace7

Any suggestions?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I expect this : [noreplace1]<noreplace2>noreplace3[noreplace4noreplace5]<noreplace6>noreplace7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the regex

```
<[^>]*>(?=[^\[\]]*\])
```

For example : http://regex101.com/r/sP8nR9/3

The code can be

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>(?=[^\[\]]*\])/', '', $str);
```

**How it matches**

- `<[^>]*>` matches anything between `<>`
- `(?=[^\[\]]*\])` look ahead assertion. asserts that the regex is followed by

  - `[^\[\]]*` nothing other than `[` or `]`
  - `\]` further followed by `]`

Answer (score 0):

> The expected output should be :
>   [noreplace1]noreplace3[noreplace4noreplace5]noreplace7

For this output, you can use `strip_tags`, wich is much simpler

```
<?php
$content="[noreplace1]<noreplace2>noreplace3[<replace1><replace2>noreplace4<replace3>noreplace5]<noreplace6>noreplace7";
$foo = strip_tags($content);
var_dump($foo);
```